# GET/POST query fields containing "http://" error 406

Tags: php, jquery, post, get, hosting

I have a shared hosting hosted by GoDaddy, already 1 year, and the whole was made by me. I have an 406 error when trying to make queries through "POST/GET" form, if the data fields contain "http://", but it's very important for me that they will be there.

One week ago it was working "http://" and i didn't change nothing, but it gives me error.

Please help me :(

Thanx.

Comment: Maybe GoDaddy updated the server. What are you trying to do with this data ? Where does it come from ?

Comment: thats an iframe link for youtube trailer, for movies. But i need the whole link.

Comment: If the link its correct, you could update your code to pass only the video ids, not all the link. If you have any trouble doing that, update the question with your code.

Comment: i need the whole link, because it's not always youtube, it would be great just with the id's but i use more than 30 video hostings for my website.